# Selenium web driver cannot recognize a link text

Tags: selenium-webdriver

in one of the web app that I am automating, I find that I came across to some elements that have no ID or class or anything associated, or associated dynamically and won't be able to capture, therefore I have to use link text, for example, "Canada", and then when I do

```
driver.FindElements(By.LinkText("Canada")).Count > 0 ,
```

I won't get a "True" although "Canada" is right there. Does anybody came across this before and have any idea why it is?

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use

```
driver.switchTo().frame("Your LinkText Frame Name");
driver.FindElements(By.LinkText("Canada")).Count > 0 ;
```

and try.

I think it may work.

Answer (score 1):

Are you sure "Canada" is indeed in a `<a>` tag ? `By.LinkText` is meant to search for anchor text

You can certainly create a XPath to search `By.xpath`. Something like "//*[contains(text(),'Canada')]" (this is the only xpath I can give you without knowing your HTML structure)